# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the first thing I really don't know is what's the problem with my code, In the browser display doesn't respond to my coding. Can someone help to solve this problem?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'imgUrl' of 'props.item' as it is undefined.

The above error occurred in the `<ScooterItem> component: react-dom.development.js:18687`

```
// Scooters Category //
import Nmax155 from '../assets/2022/products/nmax155.png';
import Fazzio from '../assets/2022/products/fazzio.png';
import VespaS125 from '../assets/2022/products/vespa.png';
import PcxHonda from '../assets/2022/products/pcxhonda.png';



const ScooterData = [
    {
        id: '1',
        brand: 'Yamaha',
        shortBrandName: 'yamaha-nmax-155',
        scooterName : 'New Yamaha Nmax 155',
        imgUrl: Nmax155 ,
        price_day: 150,
        price_week: 900,
        category: 'high',
        whatsapp : '',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        brand: 'Honda',
        shortBrandName: 'honda-pcx',
        scooterName: 'New Honda PCX',
        imgUrl: PcxHonda ,
        price_day: 150,
        price_week: 900,
        category: 'high',
        whatsapp: '',
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        brand: 'Vespa',
        shortBrandName: 'vespa-s-125',
        scooterName: 'Vespa S 125',
        imgUrl: VespaS125 ,
        price_day: 150,
        price_week: 900,
        category: 'high',
        whatsapp: '',
    },
]

export default ScooterData;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../../styles/scooteritem.css';



const ScooterItem = (props) => {
    const { imgUrl, brand, scooterName, shortBrandName, price_day, price_week, whatsapp} = props.item;

    return (
    <section className='app__scooter-item' id='scooter'>
        <Col lg='4' md='4' sm='6' className='mb-5'>
            <div className='app__scooter-items'>
                <div className='app__scooter-img'>
                    <img src={imgUrl} alt='' className='w-100' />
                </div>
                <div className='app__scooter-item-content mt-4'>
                    <h4 className='app__scooter-title text-center'>{scooterName}</h4>
                    <div className='justify-content-between d-flex align-items-center app__scotoer-item-rent'>
                       <h6 className='rent__price align-items-center gap-1'>
                        IDR{price_day} <span>/ Day</span>    
                        </h6>
                        <h6 className='rent__price align-items-center gap-1'>
                        IDR{price_week} <span>/ Week</span>
                        </h6> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className='scooter__item-info d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-3 mb-4'>
                        <span className='d-flex align-items-center gap-1'>
                            <i class="ri-e-bike-fill">{brand}</i>
                        </span>  
                    </div>
                    <button className='w-50 scooter__item-button scooter__btn-rent'>
                        <a href={whatsapp}>Rent</a>
                    </button>
                    <button className='w-50 scooter__item-button scooter__btn-details'>
                        <Link to={`/scooters/${shortBrandName}`}>Details</Link>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Col>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ScooterItem
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: As it says property 'imgUrl' of 'props.item' is undefined.

Comment: This means that `props.item` has no value and, as a consequence, you can't call `props.item.imageUrl`. You will need to check what value `props` and `props.item` have when the error occurs.

Comment: How is ScooterData passed into ScooterItem? Do show the code!